# Additional price increase and decrease in configurable option magento2

Tags: magento2

I am working with Magento 2.2.6. I want to add an additional price to the configurable option's label.

For Ex.
If there are three configurable options

```
Red - $400(Main price)
white - $850(Main price)
black - $1700(Main price)
```

let's assume main product price as $400.

Now, select options menu have to show like this:

```
Red 
white + $450
black + $1300
```

Now if i select white option label, then it needs to be update like this:

```
Red - $450
white
black + $850
```

So the price should be increase and decrease as per option selection.

Magento 1 has this feature by default coded in configurable js. But, it is not available in magento2. I need a quick solution for this.